# Scheduling a task in python

Tags: python

i'm trying to schedule a task every 5 seconds, here what i did:

```
import schedule
import time
import tweepy 
from threading import Timer

def job():
  iGen = (i for i in range(1, 6))
  for i in iGen:

    i += 1
    mymessage = "My message here " + str(i)

    print(mymessage)

schedule.every(5).seconds.do(job)

while 1:                                
   schedule.run_pending()
   time.sleep(1)
```

but the result is:

```
My message here 2 ..after 5 secs
My message here 3
My message here 4
My message here 5
My message here 6
My message here 2 ..after 5 secs
My message here 3
My message here 4
My message here 5
My message here 6
My message here 2 ..after 5 secs
My message here 3
My message here 4
My message here 5
My message here 6
```

what i need is:

```
My message here 2 ..after 5 secs
My message here 3 ..after 5 secs 
My message here 4 ..after 5 secs
My message here 5 ..after 5 secs
My message here 6 ..after 5 secs
```

sorry for the newbie question, Thank you

Comment: What do you need this for? There might be a better way to accomplish this.

Comment: auto message to be sent with an auto incremented number, please, i'm open to suggesting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your job is to loop over 2-6, printing for each. It sounds like you want the job to just print once each time it runs. This would do that, but would not number the messages.

```
import schedule
import time

def job():
    print("Message")

schedule.every(5).seconds.do(job)

while 1:                                
   schedule.run_pending()
   time.sleep(1)
```

To get numbering is a bit more complicated, but you can do it with a static variable:

```
import schedule
import time

def job():
    job.i += 1
    print("Message: " + str(job.i))
job.i = 1

schedule.every(5).seconds.do(job)

while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: after testing your code the result is every 5 secs : "Message: 2"

Comment: @MounirElfassi You are absolutely right. I was using generators totally wrong. I have edited my answer, and now works.

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to increment a number and print it every X seconds you can try something like this:

```
i = 0
while 1:
    print("My message here "+str(i))
    i++
    time.sleep(5)
```

Does it have to be threaded?

I will edit this answer if you give me more detail on how your application should work.

Comment: but how can i run this every x secs?

Comment: sorry i get it now, this was simple.. Thanks

Comment: Yeah it's the while true and the time.sleep which make it run every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is with you the **job** function!Ask yourself whether looping through 2 to 5 is a part of **every job method** or not?According to your problem description,it should only contains printing a message:

```
def job(msg,num):  #if your message is same you won't need to pass it,same for num
    print(msg+str(num))
```

then in other parts you should pass message and num  :

```
schedule.every(5).seconds.do(job)

while 1:                                
   schedule.run_pending()
   time.sleep(1)
```